# Unable to merge contacts (fails to update field)

Tags: apex, dml, dmlexception

I use the native merge functionality to glue two duplicate contacts together programmatically:

```
merge target source;
```

Yet this invokes the following error:

> 12:06:49:251 USER_DEBUG [46]|DEBUG|DML_e: Merge failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 0030-removed---tQAG; first error:
>   INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: Name.
>   Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is
>   read/write for your profile or permission set.: [Name]

I'm confused. For once, the Name field is exactly the same for both contacts. Also, I thought my Apex would run with maximum permissions in any case.

What is a good way to merge two Contacts, ideally copying tasks, attachments etc as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is not a writable field (it's a composite of multiple fields). You must use FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix, and Salutation, as appropriate. You must **not** query the Name field, or you'll get this error. The merge syntax will, as you surmise, link all child records (attachments, tasks, etc) to the surviving record.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I sort of missed the obvious. Thank you very much for your quick and insightful reply!